# Use the iframe api (youtube) with Cordova for android

Tags: android, iframe, cordova, youtube

After a good two hours of searching the Internet I can't find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to develop an application for android and iOs using Cordova. In this application I make use of the Iframe API of Youtube. I need to be aware of the end of a certain video in order to call another one.

But it seems that this API is not working on Android (but well on iOs). Does anyone has a solution for this ?

Here is what I've thought of:

- Basic embedding of a Youtube (without the API) and a custom listener to be notified of the end of a song (No idea how to do that...)
- Use a Cordova plugin for the android youtube api (the one I saw only had the possibility to load a song not having listeners)

Comment: On iOS, this might be your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090328/recently-not-playing-youtube-clip-with-iframe-player-on-uiwebview