# Recently not playing youtube clip with iframe player on UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

My iOS application uses youtube iframe player on UIWebView to play any clip with inline mode. The following code is HTML code used.

```
<html>
<head>
     <style type="text/css">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style>
</head>
 <body style="margin:0">
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/e2w8z6mI47U?playsinline=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" width="320" height="240" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
 </html>
```

Then, it is passed to `loadHTMLString` method.

That code had worked well until a recent date. But, I recently noticed that every clips I used aren't played normally. the standby view and play button is shown but, although I pushed the play button, it didn't play well. black screen was only shown.

I haven't found anything to solve the problem. Are there any changes of Youtube Iframe player or points I missed?

Answer (score 8):

I ended up solving the problem by calling `[videoView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO]`.
I don't exactly know why the method could save me. At a guess, there was a change dealing with the request for playing at youtube. I could find the following changes on youtube developer site.

> **January 28, 2014**
>
> The playsinline parameter controls whether videos play inline or
>   fullscreen in an HTML5 player on iOS. Setting the value to 1 causes
>   inline playback.
>
> The Selecting content to play section has been updated to explain how
>   to find YouTube video IDs and playlist IDs using the YouTube Data API
>   (v3) rather than the older API version.
>
> The controls parameter's definition has been updated to reflect the
>   fact that the parameter value only affects the time that the Flash
>   player actually loads in IFrame embeds. In addition, for IFrame
>   embeds, the parameter value also determines when the controls display
>   in the player. If you set the parameter's value to 2, then the
>   controls display and the Flash player loads after the user initiates
>   the video playback.

I guess that one of above changes may need extra informations which are passed from a client to youtube server for playing normally.

**UPDATE:**
Today, I identified that it works well without my solution. It seems that the problem was fixed lately.

Comment: You saved me too! If anyone finds out why this works it would be great to see an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @mustafa the solution I answered doesn't work for you?