# Youtube video stopped working on iPhone - black screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, youtube

I have a native ios app that displays youtubes, up until yesterday the app was working great, but now the app shows the youtube, only that when I touch the 'play' instead of playing the video, it just show a black screen.

My app haven't change, therefore I assume that youtube change something, but I don't know what and why.

I also cannot change the app because it was build on xcode 4.5 and apple forcing me to do an upgrade which I cannot effort...

Any idea how to approach it?

Comment: is this happening on iOS7 and iOS6 both?

Comment: @san xcode 4.5 haven't iOS 7. so my thought he is trying with iOS 6 an lower version

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: I know that XCode 4.5 does not have iOS7. But the ipa created from XCode4.5 still runs on iOS7.

Comment: It appears to be a widespread problem with youtube. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094894/youtube-embeds-in-uiwebviews-no-longer-working-in-ios).

Answer (score 0):

add webView this code

webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

see more detail : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22100003/3153903